# Doctrine/Symfony: Entity with non-mapped property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I add a property to an `Entity` Class, which should not be mapped to the database?

I need the property for a temporary value. Therefore the property should not be fetched from or persisted to the database. it neither should be a sql-calculated value, i need to set (and get) this within php code only.

Comment: Please write how do you map your object (`yml`, `xml` or `annotation`) so I can give you example.

Comment: i'm using annotations..thx in advance

Comment: Just add property as usual, just do not add mapping annotations to the property and it will not get persisted.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Writing a property without annotation should not be linked to your Database as example of an entity User.

```
class User 
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
protected $username;

protected $notPersistedProperty

}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I also added setter ang getter to have everything in order.

Comment: @Strabek Yep, php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities won't generate them

Comment: OK but how to deal with DoctrineObject hydrator when entity is bind to form ?