# Bad Performance when using a output DTO with doctrine entities with a set of relations

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

**API Platform version(s) affected**:

```
/srv/api # composer show | grep api-platform
api-platform/core                              v2.6.8           Build a fully-featured hypermedia or GraphQL API in minutes!
```

**Description**
To define the response of our API endpoints, we have used attributes on the generated Doctrine entity such as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name = "products")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'path' => '/products',
        ],
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'path' => '/products/{id}',
        ],
    ],
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => [
            'product:read',
        ],
    ],
    output: ProductOutput::class,
)]
class Product {
    .... // properties and getters+setters
}
```

The `Product` entity has a `1:n` relation to the `Variant` entity which is also a `ApiResource` with an different endpoint `/variants`. The `Variant` entity has several relations to other entities and some values of all entities are translatable with https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/translatable.md.

The performance was as expected => good enough.

---

Later on, it was required to "enrich" the response of `/products` and `/variants` with some data, which was not mapped in relations between `Product` <> additional-data | `Variant` <> additional-data, so we decided to use Outputs DTO with DataTransformers, as documented in the API-Platform docs.

The DataTransformer's method `transform` puts the data into the DTO by using therespective getters of the entities, e. g.:

```
$output                  = new ProductOutput();
$output->id              = $object->getId();
$output->category        = null !== $object->getCategory() ?
    $this->iriConverter->getIriFromItem($object->getCategory()) :
    '';
$output->identifierValue = $object->getIdentifierValue();
$output->manufacturer    = $object->getManufacturer();
$output->variants        = $object->getVariants();
```

The `$object` is a `Product` entity, in this case.

The DTO contains only public properties, such as

```
/**
 * @var Collection<int, Variant>
 */
#[Groups(['product:read'])]
public Collection $variants;
```

and the `Groups` attributes, which are also defined in the `normalizationContext` of the `ApiResource` attribute in the `Product` entity above.

After that, we found the performance had drastically deteriorated: A request to the `/products` endpoint which "lists" 30 `products` with the related `variants` needs around **25 seconds**.

After analyzing, we determined the following:

1. **without DTO**: Doctrine runs **one single** query with a lot of joins to retrieve all the related data from the database.
2. **with DTO**: Doctrine runs in sum **3.155** single queries to get the data.
3. by default, API-Platform uses `Eager-Fetching` (see https://api-platform.com/docs/core/performance/#force-eager), but it seems so that will be ignored if the `getters` of a entity are used in the DTO.
4. the serialization process needs the most time. That is maybe (also) a Symfony issue.

In a try to reduce the Doctrine queries, we created a DataProvider to fetch the related data. This actually worked, as using the DataProvider reduced the number of queries to `+/-` 50, but the serialization process also needed around 25s. So the cause of the performance problem does not seem to be the lazy-loading of doctrine, which is now done.

The question is: Why is using a DTO so much slower how would it be it possible to get performance back to an acceptable level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not possible to improve performance when using a DTO for this data-structure. Instead of a DTO and data transformer we used a Doctrine Event Listener (`postLoad`) to set the value which is a unmapped property ([Doctrine/Symfony: Entity with non-mapped property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106722/doctrine-symfony-entity-with-non-mapped-property)) now.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I guess you are mistaking EAGER and LAZY loading in doctrine. As far as I understand, EAGER loaded associations will be fully loaded immediately, while LAZY loaded associations will only be fully loaded when the property is accessed via the property getter (what is actually happening in your transformer).

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading

(There is also the EXTRA_LAZY option that won't even fully load related entities if you only access them with a couple of allowed methods)

From my opinion, as long as you are not serializing the related entities as nested documents (but as IRIs only), as far as I understand you shouldn't even need to fully load those entities. ***So LAZY (and don't accessing the related entities via getter) would be the way to go.*** This way we've been able to speed up entity loading a lot for entities which only needed to be serialized as an IRI (although we aren't using DTO and transformers).

Comment: IMHO, the reason for the poor performance is not the amount of db queries, but the handling of the DTOs on api platform or serializer side. To me it looks like the serializer is now serializing each record individually instead of serializing the whole data including the relations of the product in one shot.

Comment: The serialization of the related entity is required to achieve our requirements.

Comment: Lazy-loading or extra-lazy-loading makes no sense. The data can be retrieved with one query with joins, the other 3.154 queries are redundant. Without a DTO, 1 query is executed, WITH a DTO, 3.155 queries are executed.

Comment: Well yes, regardless of the lazy vs. eager issue, if you need to serialize the related entities, this won't be an option.

Comment: However, I don't agree with this: "To me it looks like the serializer is now serializing each record individually instead of serializing the whole data including the relations of the product in one shot." Actually every serialization of nested entities is another call to the serializer, as far as I understand there is no "one shot" serialization. And I really doubt that serializing itself is the performance bottleneck.